# Git: Push newly created local submodules up to Github and Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have a newly created local repo in which I created several submodules (based upon subfolders of the local project folder) to enable me to track changes on groups of somewhat unrelated SQL scripts  (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092715/2958633 for more info). I need to push the entire repo, including the submodules, up to Github and Bitbucket. How can I make this happen?

I may be trying to use submodules in a way that they were not designed to be used, since all of the documentation I have found involve creating submodules from already existing repos. Also, Github nor Bitbucket provide the ability to create empty submodules from within the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of submodules is to create a reference to a remote repo that you include in your main repo as a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) SHA1 ([special entry in the index)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) and a `.gitmodules` url references.

In other words, to add a submodule, you must have reference a remote repo url:

```
git submodule add -- /url/remote/repo path/to/submodule
```

So as long as you have pushed your submodules repos, you can simply add, commit and push your main repo.

Comment: Two things to add: first, the repos do not yet exist remotely anywhere. Second, I created the submodules locally using "git submodule add mod1 ./mod1". The surprise is that it worked!

Comment: @MichaelSheaver That is not how submodules are working. You need to add your submodule by referencing a empty remote repo, then add your file in it, add, commit and push, then go to the parent repo, add, commit and push.